# SQL - Financial Year YTD Calcuation

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

I am trying to calculate year to date totals grouping a query by calendar year but having a column which totals time in minutes from the beginning of the financial year (i.e from 1st April of the same year the month occurred in if the month >= April otherwise 1st April from the previous year)

I have tried this with the following script but am unable to use a case statement in the sum() over() clause.

```
    declare @yearmonth int = 4
declare @NumPreceeding int = case when right(@yearmonth,2) in (01,02,03) then 9+right(@yearmonth,1) 
                                                                                    else (((12-(right(@yearmonth,2)+8)))*(-1)) 
                                                                                                                    end
select  ColumnDescription
       ,sum(TotalMinutes) [TotalMinutes]
          ,sum(sum(TotalMinutes)) over (order by YearMonth rows between cast(@NumPreceeding as int) preceding and current row)
          ,YearMonth
from MyTable
where yearmonth between '201704' and '201706'
group by ColumnDescription ,YearMonth
order by yearmonth
```

Do you know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cumulative sums, then I would expect:

```
select ColumnDescription, YearMonth, sum(TotalMinutes) as TotalMinutes,
       sum(sum(TotalMinutes)) over (partition by ColumnDescription order by YearMonth) as running_TotalMinutes
from MyTable
where yearmonth between '201704' and '201706'
group by ColumnDescription, YearMonth
order by yearmonth;
```

If you want to do this for multiple years, then you need to extract the fiscal year.  This is a little cumbersome, but doable:

```
select ColumnDescription, YearMonth, sum(TotalMinutes) as TotalMinutes,
       sum(sum(TotalMinutes)) over (partition by ColumnDescription, v.fiscal_year order by YearMonth) as running_TotalMinutes
from MyTable t cross apply
     (values (case when right(yearmonth, 2) >= '04' then cast(left(yearmonth, 4) as int)
                   else cast(left(yearmonth, 4) as int) - 1
              end)
     ) v(fiscal_year)
group by ColumnDescription, YearMonth
order by yearmonth;
```